# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\files'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception

```
public HttpResponseMessage DownloadZipFile(List<FileModel> files)
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
    {
        zip.AlternateEncodingUsage = ZipOption.AsNecessary;
        zip.AddDirectoryByName("Files");

        foreach (FileModel file in files)
        {
            if (file.IsSelected)
            {
                //byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("files");
                string s = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);

                zip.AddFile(file.FilePath, "Files");
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Error Details

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException   HResult=0x80070002   Message=Could not find file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\files'.   Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>  
StackTrace: <Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
ZIpFile_Creation_API.Controllers.ZipAPIController.DownloadZipFile(System.Collections.Generic.List<ZIpFile_Creation_API.Models.FileModel>) in ZipAPIController.cs
[External Code]
```

Comment: Try `zip.AddDirectoryByName(Server.MapPath("Files"));`

Answer (score 0):

atleast needs some List param.

suggesting File.Exists(filePath) before reading.